# Is there a need to update a custom action's binary after each build?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, orca

I have created a c++ custom action for a setup-project application in VS Team System 2008.  Using ORCA I implemented it and inserted the binary image of the custom action.  This works okay.  Does the binary object remain intact after each subsequent build?  i.e. I assume I do not need to update the binary data unless I make a change to the custom action binary.  How does that work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Each build picks the custom action DLL from its expected path and integrates it to the binary table.